# Fastest possible rebuild of multiple projects for multiple platforms using msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution file that contains quite a few projects, a subset of which I wish to build using a continuous integration system (Jenkins, as it happens). Currently I call devenv and specify the project/platform for each, which amounts to 28 calls to devenv. If only a small change has been made, this ends up taking quite a bit of time to just do nothing in the end (many of the projects won't have changed at all).

Building the same stuff on linux, I use ninja, and the build process if nothing has changed is more or less instant.

What I would like is to be able to launch msbuild, since this seems like the tool for the job, and provide it with the list of projects/platforms to build for and let it do its job. And, of course, I would like all the per-project parallel build to happen also.

I've looked around quite a bit for the documentation, but thus far msbuild steadfastly sticks to building all the projects sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Add your projects in a solution file and run a command like this :

```
msbuild.exe SolutionFile.sln /t:Build/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32
```

You can add /m option to generate several project in parralel

Comment: My solution already contains all the projects, but I wish to only build some of them. Launching msbuild to build each is no better than launching devenv.exe to build each. I'd like to launch msbuild once, and have it build everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Use MsBuild.exe /m to build in parallel.

For extra credit, build all your configurations in parallel as well >:)

1) Ensure all of your projects that depend upon eachother have references.

2) Include all of them in a group and use Configuration Manager to remove platform and configuration combinations not supported in your solution.

3) Put on your mad scientist cap, and create a new MsBuild project that will be used to build out your solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" >
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SrcRoot Condition="'$(SrcRoot)'==''">$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) , Project.props ))</SrcRoot>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(SrcRoot)\Project.props" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <SolutionConfiguration Include="$(SrcRoot)\MySolution.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Release;Platform=x86</Properties>
        </SolutionConfiguration>
        <SolutionConfiguration Include="$(SrcRoot)\MySolution.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Debug;Platform=x86</Properties>
        </SolutionConfiguration>
        <SolutionConfiguration Include="$(SrcRoot)\MySolution.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64</Properties>
        </SolutionConfiguration>
        <SolutionConfiguration Include="$(SrcRoot)\MySolution.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64</Properties>
        </SolutionConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MsBuild BuildInParallel="true" ContinueOnError="true" Projects="@(SolutionConfiguration)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This project expects a "project.props" in the root of the branch to establish the $(SrcRoot) folder.  It will then import this project.  If this doesn't work, simply remove the <Import /> and change that to the name of the solution or any other file in the root.
Then it creates an item group that is batched in parallel by an MsBuild task.  So instead of sequentially building your different configurations, it builds them all at once.

Now combine that with something that can detect file access and writes and you'll be able to detect race conditions or areas where bits from one configuration|platform combination can overwrite another.

Comment: This is pretty close, but it builds everything in (for instance) Release Win32. I just want to build some of the projects in there, but I can't find any documentation about what I might put into the <properties> tag to make this happen. For instance Project=MyProject seems to be just ignored.

Comment: I would recommend creating new solution configuration and check/uncheck the projects you want to build. Then pass in solution config as Configuration on sln build.